# Issue finding the time dependence of the conjugate momentum of the Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I am following Peskin and Schroeder's book, trying to evaluate the following commutator:
$$
i \partial_t \pi(x,t) = \left[\pi(x,t),\int \frac{d^3 x'}{2} (\pi^2(x',t)+(\nabla \phi(x',t))^2 + m^2 \phi^2 (x',t))\right]
$$
the first commutator (with the two conjugate momenta) will vanish. So we are left with two terms:

$$
\left[\pi(x,t),\int \frac{d^3 x'}{2} ((\nabla \phi(x',t))^2\right] +m^2 \left[\pi(x,t),\int \frac{d^3 x'}{2}   \phi^2 (x',t)\right].
$$

I know how to deal with the second term, but I am having trouble on dealing with the first term, with the del squared. I tried to integrate it by parts once, to get
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left[\pi(x,t), \phi(x',t) \nabla \phi(x',t) - \int d^3 x' \phi(x',t) \nabla^2 \phi (x',t)\right].
$$
but this will leave me with a commutator of $[\pi, \phi]$ which is proportional to the delta function, but out of the integral. To me it seems like this first term should vanish (boundary term?), but I cannot properly argue why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, observe that

$$
[\pi(x,t),(\nabla\phi(x',t))^2]=\nabla\phi(x',t)[\pi(x,t),\nabla\phi(x',t)]+[\pi(x,t),\nabla\phi(x',t)]\nabla\phi(x',t)\ .
$$

Now, since in this case the nabla operator differentiates with respect to $x'$, i.e. $\nabla\equiv \nabla_{x'}$, you can write

$$
\nabla_{x'}\pi(x,t)=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad [\pi(x,t),\nabla_{x'}\phi(x',t)]=\nabla_{x'}[\pi(x,t),\phi(x',t)]=-i\nabla_{x'}\delta(x-x')\ .
$$

Hence

$$
[\pi(x,t),(\nabla\phi(x',t))^2]=-2i\ \nabla_{x'}\phi(x',t)\ \nabla_{x'}\delta(x-x').
$$

*At this point* you can integrate by parts, using

$$
\nabla_{x'}\phi(x',t)\ \nabla_{x'}\delta(x-x')\equiv -\nabla_{x'}^{2}\phi(x',t)\ \delta(x-x')
$$

under the integration sign. After integrating with the delta, you get the result you're looking for.